# How to direct custom DuckDuckGo search to specific site in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a custom search bar in HTML and jQuery.

The code I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit_on_enter').keydown(function(event) {
    // enter has keyCode = 13, change it if you want to use another button
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      this.form.submit();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outercontain">
  <div class="innercontain" align="center">
    <form action="https://google.com/" method="get">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Art">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm looking to do is limit searches to a specific site purely in html/in the URL itself. On the actual Google webpage this is easy - you could just enter `"site:website.com"` and it would be done. But in this setup I have, `name="q"` is already appended to any searches. If I get rid of the `name="q"` section, the search doesn't work properly (it just goes to google's homepage) and if I tamper with the url, then it just searches for whatever I add. DuckDuckGo is acceptable too.

Comment: You could intercept the `submit` event for the form, and append `' site:website.com'` to the `q` input

Comment: I did actually try appending the `'site:website.com'` to the `q` input... The problem is that the `q` is there to precede the search. For instance, searching for 'Red' after adding this returns the following url: `https://duckduckgo.com/?q+site%3Awebsite.com=red`, which is a link that leads nowhere.

Comment: You’ve appended the `site` part to `q` there, not the query string itself. That `site` part is just part of the query string, it's not a separate parameter

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: This is my input html at the moment. `<input autocomplete="off" class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q site:website.com" placeholder="Search Art">`

Comment: You want to take `red` and make it `red site:website.com` so that the output string is `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=red%20site%3Awebsite.com`

Comment: Changing the name to anything other than `q` will not be helpful - you’re confusing the parameter name & value

Comment: Ah, but how would I add `site:website.com` to a search automatically? I want to avoid having to type that in every time. The search bar would be on a website and only search that specific site. If I add `red site:website.com` manually then the search box technically becomes useless. I am new, so I'm not sure of the difference between params and value. Thank you

Comment: Read my original comment again

Comment: Unfortunately, Bing does not have a query parameter like Google's `as_searchsite` into which the domain name can be provided. It is a pity, as at August 2023, Bing is providing 100% coverage of a site's pages, compared to the sub-50% previously and Google's less than 4% (yes 4% for a not-so-popular site)

Comment: While DuckDuckGo does have the `sites` query parameter into which the domain name can be placed, and it uses Bing, which as at August 2023, is providing 100% coverage of a site's pages, DDG is still covering less than half of a site's pages. Perhaps DDG will soon follow suit. For comparison, Google covers less than 4% (yes 4% for a not-so-popular site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `site:website.com` as part of the value of `q` not the key.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit_on_enter').keydown(function(event) {
    // enter has keyCode = 13, change it if you want to use another button
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      this.form.q.value = "site:website.com " + this.form.q.value
      this.form.submit();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="outercontain">
  <div class="innercontain" align="center">
    <form action="https://google.com/" method="get">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Art">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side note: the snippet won't actually redirect because of stackoverflow's security on the iframe.

Comment: I do have a little issue when I'm using google.com with it though. Searching involves 2 clicks because it only redirects to google's homepage with the input box filled in, rather than actually showing results as well. DuckDuckGo works perfectly however.

Answer (score 0):

DuckDuckGo has a query parameter for this called `sites`. If supplied, it will automatically append the `site:` directive to the search query. You can just use HTML forms, no JavaScript required:

```html
<div class="outercontain">
  <div class="innercontain" align="center">
    <form action="https://duckduckgo.com/" method="get">
      <input autocomplete="off" class="submit_on_enter" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Art">
      <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="example.com">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```